# sed: -e expression #1, char 66: unterminated `s' command

Tags: linux, bash, sed, error-handling

After some text manipulations I got the output: " 75 queen". I sent it like this:

```
..( 75 queen ).. | sed 's/ \([0-9]*\) \(q.*) /The word \2 with \1 appearances.'
```

For this code I got the error "sed: -e expression #1, char 66: unterminated `s' command.
What does it mean?

Comment: Two things: you're missing a `/` at the end, and there is an unescaped closing parenthesis after `q.*`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues that need to be solved in your `sed` expression:

1. The replace command must end with `/` plus any modifiers.
2. There are several regex "flavors" and `sed` uses the Basic POSIX regular expression, which means that `()` should be escaped in order to capture matching groups. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions/400316#400316) for details.
3. It seems you want to capture `75` and `queen`. To do that you need to specify that the first group should match any number of digits and the second group should capture `q` followed by any number of characters. `*` will match 0 or more of repetitions and `+` (that should be escaped) will match 1 or more repetitions.

Considering that, the following `sed` expression should do the trick:

```
echo '..( 75 queen )..' | sed 's/ \([0-9]\+\) \(q.*\) /The word \2 with \1 appearances./'
```